# how to get loaded sources via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need two things:

1. Getting links of all loaded internal and external sources (like javascript, webassembly, css)
2. Getting content of these sources files without using ajax or xhr request. Is is possible to get the content by using chrome's sources? i don't know it, maybe there some functionality for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

for(var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++){

scripts[i].src; 

}
```

this code helps to get list of javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < document.scripts.length; i++) { 
    console.log(document.scripts[i]);
}
```

This will return you all loaded scripts